# Update neo4j node with new relations, using py2neo

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

My code adds nods and creates relations. It updates when the connection is a->b, a->c, a->d,  it works(to node a new relations are added), but when I add connection f->a then a second node with name a is created. How can I make it to update the existing node a?

```
graph = Graph()
with open('test2') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        result = line.split('\t')
        category1 = graph.merge_one("Category", "name",result[0][result[0].rfind(':')+1:])
        category2 = graph.merge_one("Category", "name",result[1][result[1].rfind(':')+1:])
        print result[0][result[0].rfind(':')+1:] +"|"+result[1][result[1].rfind(':')+1:]
        graph.create_unique(Path(category1, "SubCategoryOf", category2))
```

My test files is:

> Category:Wars_involving_Burma Category:Wars_by_country
>   Category:Wars_involving_Burma Category:Military_history_of_Burma
>   Category:Wars_involving_Burma Category:Foreign_relations_of_Burma
>   Category:World_War_II Category:Wars_involving_Bulgaria
>   Category:World_War_II Category:Wars_involving_Burma

In this example

> Category:Wars_involving_Burma

is created twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your example, I don't get a node twice. From your question I can't tell how many 'Category:...' you have in each line. From how you split the line I assumed it's always two. One possible issue is that you don't remove line endings, so one of your 'Category:Wars_involving_Burma' nodes might have a newline character at the end. Also what you pasted is `space` separated, not `\t`.

Here is a suggestion how to improve your code, assuming your file looks like http://paste.ubuntu.com/10874106/

```
graph = Graph()

with open('test2') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        # strip the line ending first, then split by whitespace
        # I assume every line has to category entries?
        result = line.rstrip().split()

        # getting the category name is easier and more readable like this
        category1 = graph.merge_one("Category", "name", result[0].split(':')[1])
        category2 = graph.merge_one("Category", "name", result[1].split(':')[1])

        print result[0].split(':')[1] + '\t' + result[1].split(':')[1]

        # you don't need a Path here        
        graph.create_unique((category1, "SubCategoryOf", category2))
```

In addition, if you want your "Category" nodes to be unique, you should have a uniqueness constraint on the "name" property of "Category" nodes.

Cypher:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Category) ASSERT n.name IS UNIQUE
```

py2neo:

```
graph.schema.create_uniqueness_constraint('Category', 'name')
```

Comment: Thank you, Martin. I already found the issue it was the trailing new line (\n). Because of that, although  name looked the same in the database, it was different.
I'm marking your answer as correct because your suggested rstrip() would have solved that.